# Matching regular and dash separated word with regex

Tags: php, regex

I want to match words seperated by dash `-` and also regular word.
Currently i'm using this regular expression
`\b(word|someother|xyz|....|word50)\b // upto 50 words`
but now the trouble is I also want match words like

```
w-ord
w-o-r-d
some-oth-e-r
x-y-z
```

so instead of putting `(-)?` after every character manually like this

```
\b(w(-)?o(-)?r(-)?d|w(-)?o(-)?r(-)?d|someother|....|word50)\b
```

is there any shorter way to do this with regex so it can match `-` also.
As list is too long I want a shorter way

Comment: which `language/tool` are you using!

Comment: you don't need to do it with regex **only**..you can instead extract words and then match it against a list of your valid words

Comment: I can't use this in my case right now. Thanks @Anirudh

Comment: so in your system, `w-ord` will be 1 word? or 2 words?

Comment: @RaheelHasan I did't get you.

Comment: what if the word is `w--ord` or `w---ord`? pick a standard. if it doesn't fall in it, then discard it.

Comment: @itachi don't want to match them

Answer (score 1):

You can probably match it like this:

```
$regex = '#\b(word|someother|xyz|....|word50)\b#';
$ret = preg_match($regex, preg_replace('#(?<=\w)-(?=\w)#', '', $str), $m);
```

i.e. if dash comes between 2 word characters then remove all dash (hyphens) from strings first and then match.

Comment: Look OK to me but not exactly what I want here. Will think about this.

Comment: my question exactly. what you want? You didn't write the expected output.

Comment: You might want to use lookarounds instead of captures.  I think otherwise w-o-r-d would become wo-rd, as matches cannot overlap.

Answer (score 0):

how about this (From what I could understand from your question):

`/[a-zA-z]{1}[a-zA-z\-]{0,48}[a-zA-z]{1}/`

it will match all alphabetic words (upto 50) and including '-' in them (but not at the start or at the end)

Comment: Don't want to match all there is a word boundy